# Verifying roles & authentication with Passport.js

Tags: node.js, express, roles, passport.js

So I'd like to make some routes in an API that will show different data based on the user role, defined in MongoDB.  Here's a sampling of what I have right now, it works...

```
router.get('/test', passport.authenticate('bearer', {session: false}), function (req, res) {
    if (req.user.role == "premium") {
        return res.send('you can see this content');
    }
    else {
        return res.send('you can not see this content');
    }
})
```

However, the end goal is to present at least **something** to the user, even if they're not logged in or authenticated with the right kind of role.

```
router.get('/test', passport.authenticate('bearer', {session: false}), function (req, res) {
    if (req.user.role == "premium") {
        return res.send('this is premium content');
    }
    else {
        // could be hit by another role, or no user at all
        return res.send([some truncated version of the premium content]);
    }
})
```

Which I would think I'd figure out how to work, but I don't know how to specify the same route which possibly could be hit without any Authorization header in the request.

Is this possible in Passport.js/Express?

Comment: You'll have to build your own fork in ordoer to allow this I believe

Comment: Fork the passport repo and add the feature, is that what you mean?

Comment: Rather this one I think. If you are using it. https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http-bearer. The lines that you should take a look at are these ones https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http-bearer/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L89-101

Comment: I gotcha, sure, definitely worth looking into.  However I think I would need to offer another checker because on some content, I'd still like to kick people out if they're not authorizing (like it is by default).

Comment: Then your modified version of your passport middleware should perhaps look at the current route and kick if it matches a specific regex. Or the route callback can still kick by res.send(401)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would suggest that you use HTTP status codes and an error object, this is a common API convention and it allows your API users to know what's happening and why:

```
app.get('/premium-resource', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('bearer', function(err, user) {
    if (user){
      if (user.role === 'premium'){
        return res.send(200,{userContent:'you are a premium user'});
      }else{
        return res.send(403,{
          'status': 403,
          'code': 1, // custom code that makes sense for your application
          'message': 'You are not a premium user',
          'moreInfo': 'https://myawesomeapi.io/upgrade'
        });
      }
    }else{
      return res.send(401,{
        'status': 401,
        'code': 2, // custom code that makes sense for your application
        'message': 'You are not authenticated.',
        'moreInfo': 'https://myawesomeapi.io/docs'
      });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Disclaimer: I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com) and we put a lot of thought into API authentication and design, we have a really presentation on the topic:

https://stormpath.com/blog/designing-rest-json-apis/

Comment: Good idea!  However anyone not logged in and seeing the premium content in their stream would essentially get an error in their console, right?  Is this good general practice?  Especially if an angular app is listening for error codes and responding with other routes/templates?

Comment: Your client (an Angular app, etc) does need to read these status codes or error messages and respond accordingly - how you show it to the user of the client.. that's totally up to you :)

Answer (score 9):

The solution is to limit the content in the view rather than the route.

```
router.get('/test', authenticationMiddleware, function(req, res){
    var premiumFlag = req.user.role;
    res.send('premiumontent', {role: premiumFlag});
});
```

**premiumContent.jade**

```
p This content is visible to all users

- if role === "premium"
    p this content is only visible to premium users
```

Comment: A good solution if using jade, for sure.  What if I'm not using Jade though?  I'd like to keep these routes strictly on an API.

Comment: If you're building an API you should edit the question to say so, that way we can offer API specific answers :)

Comment: Is Jade really that common to assume that it's implemented in a NodeJS app, though?

Comment: I'm going to guess it is the most commonly used templating engine for nodejs but regardless all of them are similar enough that the example can be easily translated from Jade to any other one.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I've found to my answer is to use an adaptation of the [Passportjs.org](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/) documentation.

In the routes I need to return data, whether a user is logged in or not I can use something like:

```
// Test to check for authentication
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('bearer', function(err, user, info) {
    if (user)
        // check user's role for premium or not
        if (user.role == "premium")
            return res.send('user is premium')
        else
            return res.send('user is not premium');
    else
        // return items even if no authentication is present, instead of 401 response
            return res.send('not logged in');
  })(req, res, next);
});
```