# make user groups w/ passport

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

What's the easiest way to make user groups, using passport, mongoose, express & ejs?
I want to make something like the Google Classroom app:

- normal users being able to enter private groups
- teachers being able to post information like homework
- users being able to upload their lessons or homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are commonly called roles. Personally I followed this answer: [Verifying roles & authentication with Passport.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895219/verifying-roles-authentication-with-passport-js).

There are many tutorials but they heavily depend on your strategy. Search for passportjs roles and there must be a tutorial to satisfy your needs.