# Authentication based on user role mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, passport.js

I'm building a project where I have 3 types of Users: **Admin**, **Worker** and **User**. I'm using mongo and I've set up three different schemas based on the different roles.

While trying to make a single form of login/register authentication using passport.js, and redirecting users to the according pages, I've seen some solutions that envolve using only one table of Users and giving them a field: **role**.

**Questions**: Is it possible to make a single form of login given I have 3 tables of users? Am I better off making 3 logins? Is that even possible? What's the best way going forward?

Essentially I was able to create a login/register authentication for the **User** and after that I decided to redo passport logic for each table of users. It didn't work and I saw somewhere it couldn't be done. Thank you in advance, I hope this isn't too dumb.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verifying roles & authentication with Passport.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895219/verifying-roles-authentication-with-passport-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once looking into the [Connection String URI Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) for `MongoDB` it clearly shows the possibility to use a different internal DB as a source for authentication if we use `authSource` .

The roles of the users in the DB shall be determined at the DB engine-side rather than the login form. The user only has to enter a valid username and password. Looking up the roles and accessibility questions should be left for the DB engine.

I suggest that you would create an additional schema at the root level that has the allowed usernames and their corresponding allowed schema (the ones that you have separately created). Use is as a tread stone to access the real deal.